# Python subprocess hangs with psql command

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

I am running the following piece of python code (runs a command in a shell and grabs its output or reports an error)

```
import sys
import subprocess
def check_output(args, communicate=None, quiet=False, **kwargs):
    for stream in ["stdout", "stderr"]:
        kwargs.setdefault(stream, subprocess.PIPE)

    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
    try:
        out, err = proc.communicate()
    finally:
        for f in (proc.stdout, proc.stderr):
            if f is not None:
                f.close()
        proc.wait()

    if kwargs["stderr"] != subprocess.PIPE:
        err = ""

    if proc.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception(args, proc.returncode, err)
    else:
        if not quiet:
            sys.stderr.write(err)
            sys.stderr.flush()
    return out
```

with the following arguments:

```
env = dict(
        PGHOST='{pg_host}',
        PGPORT='{pg_port}',
        PGDATABASE='{pg_dbname}',
        PGUSER='{pg_user}',
        PGPASSWORD='{pg_password}',
      )

cmd = ['psql', '-c', "INSERT INTO {ft_geom} SELECT * FROM {ft_geom_in};"].format(**tables)
check_output(cmd, shell=True, env=env)
```

Here `env` simply contains the `PG[HOST|USER|DATABASE|PORT|..]` environment variables and `tables` contains just the names of those 2 tables. When I run this code, it hangs indefinitely on `proc = subprocess.Popen` call. I am using python `2.6.5` on `Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS`

I check that no tables are locked with the following:

```
SELECT a.datname,
         c.relname,
         l.transactionid,
         l.mode,
         l.granted,
         a.usename,
         a.current_query, 
         a.query_start,
         age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age", 
         a.procpid 
    FROM  pg_stat_activity a
     JOIN pg_locks         l ON l.pid = a.procpid
     JOIN pg_class         c ON c.oid = l.relation
    ORDER BY a.query_start;
```

And it shows that all the locks were granted. Not sure where else to look at. I need `shell=True` because the commands are sometimes more complex, requiring bash pipes. I know I should ideally pass `stdout.PIPE` of one command to the other, but its not possible to change this at the moment.

Running the very same command from bash directly works as expected, also, running without `shell=True` works

Comment: Full stop. You're reinventing https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output, ignoring Python's ability to talk to PostgreSQL directly (with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2 for example) and you're doing it in a way which is vulnerable for SQL injection. Don't go that way, please.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo this is legacy code and unfortunately I need to fix it. I will try your suggestion on `check_output`. I can't use `psycopg` directly because usually queries are more complex and sometimes they need to pipe to external binaries.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo do you have any idea why does the currently written code not work?

Comment: You're just begging for this kind of trouble with `shell=True` - you could just wrap whatever magic you want in a bash script and call this script with `Popen` instead. You're also calling `wait()` while `communicate()` already waits for a child to terminate and it's documented that `wait()` can cause deadlock. Actually everything in `finally:` block is pointless. Still `shell=True` is the biggest mistake. Play with pipes in Python or make a bash script as I've written in my first sentence. You're doing all the non recommended things here... Even results from psycopg2 can be piped from Python.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo thanks for your comments. I will most probably use `check_output` from python

Comment: You can use psycopg2 and pipe output to external binaries, too. Really, invoking `psql` like this is rarely a good idea, and *especially* without extreme care in argument handling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't filter newline characters in tokens passed to `check_output`, then shell would hang waiting for more input. So make sure you escape the tokens when you pass them to shell.